# if statement in plsql package

Tags: if-statement, plsql

I have six insert blocks (job, position, grade, etc.) in one package something like:

```
create or replace package body XX_package_cust
AS

PROCEDURE main_procedure( p_entity In VARCHAR2 default 'ALL')

is

begin

if p_entity='Job'
then
--execute job block

elsif p_entity='Position'

--execute postion block

elsif p_entity='Grade'

--execute grade block
end if;

end;
```

Now in the above if else i want to pass `'ALL'` in p_entity such that if `all` is passed all these blocks should be executed and if 'job', grade position only the respective blocks should be executed.

In this for example in job section

```
begin

    begin

    insert into job_i
    --------

    end;

    begin
    insert into job_x
    ----
    end;
   end;
```

Now if I include if else in each... I will have to do something like :

```
begin
if p_entity ='JOB'
then
    begin

    insert into job_i
    --------

    end;

    begin
    insert into job_x
    ----
    end;
end if;
   end;
```

That is if else for each and every block. Is there any other way out

Comment: I dont understand the problem.. just put it in an if else like you did

Answer (score 3):

You could make each condition check for both the specific value or `'ALL'`. Note that you'd have to replace the `elsif` statements with simple `if`s:

```
if p_entity IN ('ALL', 'Job')
then
--execute job block
end if;

if p_entity IN ('ALL', 'Position')
--execute position block
end if;

if p_entity IN ('ALL', 'Grade')
--execute grade block
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE body XX_package_cust
AS
  PROCEDURE main_procedure(
      p_entity IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'ALL')
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF p_entity ='Job' THEN
      --execute job block
      dbms_output.put_line('Job block executed');
    elsif p_entity='Position' THEN
      --execute postion block
      dbms_output.put_line('Position block executed');
    elsif p_entity='Grade' THEN
      --execute grade block
      dbms_output.put_line('Grade block executed');
    elsif p_entity='All' THEN
      --execute job block
      dbms_output.put_line('Job block executed');
      --execute postion block
      dbms_output.put_line('Position block executed');
      --execute grade block
      dbms_output.put_line('Grade block executed');
    END IF;
  END;
END;
```